# Как сохранить картинку по прямой ссылке?

Tags: php, изображения

Здравствуйте.

```
http://site.ru/image.jpeg
```

Короче, как сохранить картинку по конкретной ссылке?

Comment: Кароче а что вы пробовали сами? Что не получилось?

Comment: "Кароче", не дают народу включить мозг. @Gedweb, к сожалению, ответил

Comment: ну уж извините... =)
upd: есть ещё несколько вариантов

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В простейшем случае

```
copy("http://site.ru/image.jpg","save_dir/image.jpg");
```

Если URL имеет пробелы и прочие символы желательно обернуть его `urlencode()`

При этом должна быть установлена директива сервера

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

о чём можно узнать используя phpinfo()

Comment: Если уж вы даёте ответ на тривиальный вопрос, расскажите о всех вариантах и тонкостях.

Comment: поздно уже, а вообще - "кароче" какой вопрос, такой ответ
когда-то я спрашивал подобное, просто у человека в мозге — картинка не есть файл. Тут даже в этом скорее ответ

Comment: хочется дополнить ваш ответ директивой allow_url_fopen, чтобы не возникало казусов. Она должна быть включена.

Comment: плюсую, однако автор вопроса вряд ли поймёт

Comment: да ваще способов несколько, но если есть curl я предпочитаю его использовать, он безотказный (: